# whereNotIn not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using the Laravel 5 query builder, but can't seem to find any rows when I use the whereNotIn function.

Here's the code I am using:

```
BookingDates::where('id', $id)->whereNotIn('token', [$token])->count()
```

It should return a count of 1.

However, when I remove the whereNotIn clause it works:

```
BookingDates::where('id', $id)->count()
```

Comment: But what it returns ?

Comment: It returns a count of 0

Comment: are you sure you have matching records in your table ?

Comment: Yes i've checked it a thousand times :)

Comment: What is inside the `$token` ? Can you do `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
return end($queries);` ?

Comment: The token value is N4W5qyUR4Fm0RDoqzN0wztYqECtmGRQxWsC6YbYmFbnfQOELdtmV7iJ0gvUq

Comment: When I try to do getQueryLog after the query I get: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), &quot;boolean&quot; given.

Comment: change `return end($queries);` to `print_rend($queries)`

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\print_rend()

Comment: the current Eloquent query generates this SQL raw : SELECT * from 'bookingRates' where id = $id and token NOT IN($token). Is that you want ?

Comment: I think so - my token field is null so if I provide a value for token it should return count = 1 right?

Comment: I think it has something to do with token being a null column...